# Is it possible to replace the whole JSON in a column with a new JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have a code which executes a script where I want to update a column in a table with a completely new JSON data. I know it can be also done using `Json_Modify` but I want to know if it is possible to replace the old JSON data with new.

Code which executes the script as a raw SQL query:

```
public async Task Run(Args args)
{
    var scrPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "FolderName", args.subFolderName);

    var dataChangeSqlPath = Path.Combine(scrPath, args.DataChangeSqlFileName);
    var query = await this.GetSql(dataChangeSqlPath);
    await this.db.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(query);
}

private async Task<string> GetSql(string path)
{
    var sql = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);
    return sql.ToString();
}
```

And this is the script it is trying to execute:

```
And this is the script it is trying to execute:

DECLARE @answers_json NVARCHAR(max);

BEGIN TRY   
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        SELECT
             @answers_json = N'{"CONST_TRUE":{"type":"specified","boolValue":true}}'

        BEGIN
            UPDATE [dbo].[ColumnName] 
            SET  
               AnswersJson= @answers_json
            WHERE 
                Id=2 AND Number=1;

    END
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    SELECT
        @error_message = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @error_severity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @error_state = ERROR_STATE();
    RAISERROR (@error_message, @error_severity, @error_state);
END CATCH
```

It throws and error:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

But when I execute the script directly in SQL Server then it works fine.

Any help/suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: `Input string was not in a correct format` is not an SQL error. It is coming from C# ans indicates you are trying to parse something such as a number or date from a string and it's failing. However your C# code has no parsing, so there is something going on that you are not showing.

Comment: I must say: that T-SQL error handling is fundamentally broken. There was no need for a transaction on a single statement, as all statements are auto-commit. If you *do* need a transaction then you *must* use `SET XACT_ABORT ON;`. And the `CATCH` is broken because you end up only returning one error if there are multiple, and you wipe the actual error number. You should instead *not* `CATCH` any errors in T-SQL, and instead catch them in C#. I also question the actual query: it seems you are injecting the `Id` and `Number` values

Comment: To add to the <broken error handling> point, you should NOT create a resultset containing your error information (which most callers will not expect or handle correctly) and then throw your own version of the original error.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestions but It did not answer my question. I want to know if there is a way to simply replace an old json with a new json.

Comment: @Charlieface : I shared the C# code which is executing the script, so I guess ExecuteSqlRawAsync does the parsing.

Comment: I found the issue with input json. ExecuteRawSqlAync cannot parse '{' and '}'. So the fix is to replace them with '{{' and '}}' and then it works fine.

Comment: No that's not the answer. The answer is to use proper parameterization, which `ExecuteRawSql` supports. For example `ExecuteRawSqlAsync("INSERT YourTable (col) VALUES ({0})", yourJsonVariable)`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) and [Prem Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11011498/prem-raj). Posting your discussions as answer to help other community members.

Use correct parameterization which `ExecuteRawSql` supports. For example `ExecuteRawSqlAsync("INSERT YourTable (col) VALUES ({0})", yourJsonVariable)`